# In a legal evidence submission packet, what is common nomenclature for different types of articles?

Tags: evidence, civil-procedure, witnesses, litigation, pro-se

For example one might have exhibit 1, exhibit 2, and so on, but also various witness statements. Are these statements themselves also *exhibits*? Where else can one find references of these sorts of organisational and naming conventions? Where do they come from?

Comment: In what jurisdiction? Many legal systems don't even have "legal evidence submission packets".

Answer (score 2):

When submitting evidence to the court, basically everything is going to be labeled as an "exhibit," including pieces of physical evidence, photographs, videos, audio recordings, affidavits, deposition transcripts, and so on.

Comment: Where does this convention arise from or where is it defined?

Comment: It's just a very informal rule, handed down from centuries of experience. There are certainly going to be some jurisdictions that have it committed to writing, but I don't know of anywhere that uses different names for these different categories of evidence.

Comment: If there's a specific jurisdiction you're interested in, we may be able to get you a more specific answer.

Comment: I’m interested in American and English jurisdictions.

Comment: That's quite a lot of jurisdictions. The rules are going to vary between and even among them. Some of them may come down to the individual judge's preferences.